# How to run specified parts of python code

Tags: python

I need to know if there is a command that allows you to execute specific lines of a larger script in python. Do insert an if at the beginning of the script like this (pseudocode, values is an input parameter). 
I do not want to insert the whole script inside the conditions because the code would be too long and because there are other conditions.

```
if values ​​== x:
     execute lines 1,2,3
else:
     execute lines 4,5,6
```

Comment: Why not put those "lines" into functions?

Comment: or put them into the python console if you just want to "test" something fast

Comment: or split them into modules for later use and better maintenance.

Comment: "command that allows you to execute specific lines" Yes, they are called "functions" https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: You could just write Functions and call them when required.

Comment: This looks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem .

Tell us, why do you want to do this? You can do this programmatically, yes, but I am 99% sure that there is better and much easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely try creating a function for each group of lines. This can be done like so:

```
def name_of_function1():
    line of code 1
    line of code 2
    line of code 3

def name_of_function2():
    line of code 4
    line of code 5
    line of code 6
```

You can then call the functions later in your program like so:

```
if values ​​== x:
   name_of_function1()
else:
   name_of_function2()
```